# Windows Phone Digital Sign XML

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8

Is it possible to sign XML in the Windows Phone 8 Silverlight project? I googled a lot and found nothing. The `SignedXML` object doesn't exist for mobile. It is mandatory for the bank that I have corporated with.

Comment: Did you read this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229745(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: Yep, but there is no `System.Security.Cryptography.Xml` namespace for windows phone. The problem is this.

Comment: ops sorry. I didn't see your last tag :/

Comment: AFAIK you can't sign xml in WP8.

Answer (score 0):

I solved it. Actually, it is possible with a 3rd party tool (**BouncyCastle**). Here is a full code and documentation [here](http://huseyinelmas.net/xml-dijital-imzalama_35.html).

Full source code without documentation is below:

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security.Cryptography;
using System.Text;
using Org.BouncyCastle.Crypto.Parameters;
using Org.BouncyCastle.OpenSsl;

namespace hsynlms.Classes
{
    public class Cryptography
    {
        public string GetSHA1withRSAKey(string pemTxtFilePath, string sData)
        {
            try
            {
                if (!File.Exists(pemTxtFilePath))
                {
                    throw new Exception("PEM (txt) file not found.");
                }

                using (var reader = File.OpenText(pemTxtFilePath))
                {
                    var pemReader = new PemReader(reader);
                    var bouncyRsaParameters = (RsaPrivateCrtKeyParameters)pemReader.ReadObject();

                    var rsaParameters = new RSAParameters();
                    rsaParameters.Modulus = bouncyRsaParameters.Modulus.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
                    rsaParameters.P = bouncyRsaParameters.P.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
                    rsaParameters.Q = bouncyRsaParameters.Q.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
                    rsaParameters.DP = bouncyRsaParameters.DP.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
                    rsaParameters.DQ = bouncyRsaParameters.DQ.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
                    rsaParameters.InverseQ = bouncyRsaParameters.QInv.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
                    rsaParameters.D = bouncyRsaParameters.Exponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned();
                    rsaParameters.Exponent = bouncyRsaParameters.PublicExponent.ToByteArrayUnsigned();

                    var privateKey = new RSACryptoServiceProvider();
                    privateKey.ImportParameters(rsaParameters);

                    var sha = new SHA1Managed();

                    UTF8Encoding str = new UTF8Encoding(true);
                    byte[] signedData = privateKey.SignData(str.GetBytes(sData), sha);
                    var result = Convert.ToBase64String(signedData);

                    return result;
                }
            }
            catch (Exception)
            {
                throw new Exception("Signing SHA1 with RSA failed.");
            }
        }
    }
}
```